# Create grouped Bar chart with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a chart like the below

[image]

My current dataframe looks like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"uipath_report": [10], "automation_anywhere_report": [15],  "uipath_login": [18],  "automation_anywhere_login": [20] })`

I tryed to look some examples

Comment: `df.T.plot.bar()`?

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to group separate uipath_report, automation_anywhere_report and  uipath_login, automation_anywhere_login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract(r'(?P<Lvl2>.*)_(?P<Lvl1>.*)'))
ax = df.set_axis(mi, axis=1).stack().droplevel(0).plot.bar(rot=45)
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

```
# Alternative: df.squeeze().set_axis(mi).unstack(level='Lvl2')
>>> df.set_axis(mi, axis=1).stack().droplevel(0)
Lvl2    automation_anywhere  uipath
Lvl1                               
login                    20      18
report                   15      10
```